# Problem installing ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, boot, windows

While I was trying to install ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows 7 on a seperate partiton on my PC, the ubuntu installation failed; now i can't boot into windows 7 anymore. When I inserted the hard disk into an external source to read its contents, I found about 6 partitons present there, while there were only  3 before. I saw that it has copied some linux files to one of the partitons.

What do I do now to be able to at least boot my Windows 7?

Comment: The simplest method is reinstall ubuntu and and format the drive which is created by failed ubuntu installation

Answer (score 1):

If your install has failed you probably have 2 main options to get everything up and running again.

1 . Install ubuntu again

To reinstall ubuntu put your live disc in and go through the setup again, when you get the the screen asking if you want to install alongside windows, replace windows or configure manually select configure manually. Then identify the new partition that has been created with your partial linux files on, format it and select that as your install location. Then continue with your installation normally. Ubuntu will then start the installation over again and when completed will set up your GRUB with both operating systems listed when you boot.

2 . Restore the Windows 7 boot and worry about ubuntu later

Insert your Windows 7 Disc 
Press a key when you are prompted.
Select a language, a time, a currency, a keyboard or an input method, and then click Next.
Click Repair your computer.
Click the operating system that you want to repair, and then click Next.
In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Command Prompt.
Type Bootrec.exe, and then press ENTER. This will give you a guide on how to use the tool which you can also find here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392. But what you need to do is to fix the boot by typing `bootrec /FixBoot`

Personally I would recommend the 1st method as if you want ubuntu in the future you will have to do it at some point anyway so there is no point in fixing Windows 7 just to replace it with ubuntu again.

Answer (score 0):

did you use **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7**? This automatically creates new partitions for Ubuntu, at least a `/`(root) where Ubuntu will reside and a swap partition(used when you run the OS). That's why there are new partitions. If those partitions are still there, you can find what happened during your install by looking into the drive where Ubuntu files are copied and going to `var\log\installer\syslog`. And for booting into Windows 7, try the repair or rescue option from the Windows 7 DVD.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool to fix boot related issues is Super Grub Disk. You can get it [here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/). If everything goes well (and it should) you will be able to rescue both Ubuntu and Windows.
It comes in ISO format that you can burn to a CD or a USB drive.